# PythonChallenge. Find rare characters in the mess below

Tags: python

I'm trying to learn programming via [PythonChallenge](http://www.pythonchallenge.com) (I have no background in programming at all) and now I'm stuck on this [challenge](http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/ocr.html), which requires me to find rare characters in the mess. The mess is in the source code of that page, which I've put in the file 'py.txt'.

I've tried this code below and it prints just this: `[('t', 2), ('e', 1), ('x', 1)]`, but the most interesting part is that isn't the right answer i think.

```
from collections import Counter

with open('C:/py.txt', 'r') as f:
    text = f.read()

c = Counter("text")
print(c.most_common())
```

When you look at the source code on the page and search for some characters (let's say 'a') [image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RralQ.png) it shows you that 'a' is in the list but it doesn't appear in the code output.

Please, help, I need to find all of those 'rare' characters. Thanks!

Oh, and also, I want to ask you how to learn Python from scratch. Maybe you have some good books to recommend or some online-resources (it would be better if it had some practical-homework stuff like doing small projects which don't require much math). Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is the definition of 'rare' in this context?

Comment: @LutzHorn I don't know. Everything I know is on the webpage. Maybe characters which appear less then 10 times. I don't even know.

Comment: Oh come on... how is it not obvious what the result `[('t', 2), ('e', 1), ('x', 1)]` is and thus what your mistake is?

Comment: As I've said I don't have a background in programming :)

Comment: @StefanPochmann I was asking for help and now for insult. If you can't help - then just move on. I wasn't asking you specifically. Why ya'll just want to say that someone is stupid?

Comment: I'm not thinking "stupid", I'm thinking "lazy". I mean, seriously... the result you get is two "t", one "e", one "x"... where could that *possibly* come from? Could it *perhaps* be from the string "text"? How did you not see this?

Comment: @StefanPochmann I just didn't thought about this. In one example somewhere I've seen that the text file was in quotemarks that's why I thought like that. Now that someone has pointed me I'll try not to make the same error later. It's just the way learning works. Errors will be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the code you are looking for is:

```
from collections import Counter

with open('C:/py.txt', 'r') as f:
    text = f.read()

c = Counter(text)
print(c.most_common())
```

without quotation marks around the word 'text'.

This is because instead of analysing the variable 'text', which contains the the information you want to analyse, you were analysing the string '"text"' which has two 't's one 'e' and one 'x'.

In answer to the other part of your question think a good resource for learning python is [the google python class](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/).

Comment: And how do I print those uncommon letters so they make a word 'equality'?

Comment: If you want a complete solution, you can find that by googling. If you want to learn programming, try to solve it yourself. Start by reading the documentation for  `Counter`. https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#counter-objects

Answer (score 0):

To get you started:

```
>>> with open("mess.txt") as f:
...     counts = {}
...     for line in f:
...         for c in line.strip():
...             counts[c] = counts.get(c, 0) + 1
...     print(counts)
... 
{'+': 6038, 't': 1, '$': 6008, '!': 6057, 'u': 1, 'y': 1, '^': 6004, '%': 6072, 'e': 1, 'l': 1, 'q': 1, '(': 6124, '*': 6011, 'i': 1, ')': 6154, '#': 6081, ']': 6127, '&': 6029, '_': 6083, 'a': 1, '}': 6081, '{': 6028, '[': 6080, '@': 6114}
```

How to get the characters that are rare is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Okay, the word is 'equality' but why my code didn't work?